# How to sent a value from JavaScript to a form and get the value as form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fullcalendar script. I have already created a event for today (for eg), now I want to edit it, so on click on today's date I have to send a value from a JavaScript to my form to edit this event.

This is my onclick JavaScript function

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function(){
      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $.getScript(event.edit_url, function() {
          $('#event_id').val(event.id);
        });
      }
    });
  })
};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

The value from `$('#event_id').val(event.id);` I'm getting in my form as 32. You can see it in form input field below form

```
<form class="simple_form edit_event" id="edit_event_#{#event_id}" action="/securities/events/#{#event_id}" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
        <input type="hidden" value="32" name="event[id]" id="event_id">
</form>
```

My problem is

The same event id 32, I want to append in my form id as `id="edit_event_32"` and in form action `action="/securities/events/32"`.

Comment: You can try like `$('#event_id').parent().attr('id','edit_event_'+event.id);`..Try it..Add it after `$('#event_id').val(event.id);`

Comment: Feels like an XY problem: instead of dynamically changing the `action` attribute on the form, why not just make a request using `$.post`?

Comment: Thanks @Lal  this worked for id. Any way to do the same to action?

Comment: @Terry some problems. if this way works it would be easy for me.

Comment: @SreRoR check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `parent()` method to get the parent of an element. After getting the parent, you can just set the `id` attribute using the jQuery `attr()` method. The code would be as below.

```
$('#event_id').parent().attr('id','edit_event_'+event.id);
```

Now, to set the `form` action, you can still use the same technique. The code would be as below.

```
$('#event_id').parent().attr('action','/securities/events/'+event.id);
```